# python 3 getting error type error '<' not supported between instances of 'int and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

def challenges():
    Name = input('Hello Please enter your name?: ')
    while True:
        choice = input('Hi '+Name+' there are 30 challenges to reveiw please enter your choice between 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15: ')
        if choice == '1':
            user_age = int(input('How old are you?: '))
            print ('You are',user_age,'years old')

```
    elif choice == '2':
        user_num1 = int(input('Hi '+Name+' please enter your first number: '))
        user_num2 = int(input('Please enter your second number: '))
        total = user_num1+user_num2
        average = total/2
        print (average)

    elif choice == '3':
        width = int(input('Please enter your width: '))
        height = int(input('Please enter your height: '))
        area = width*height
        print ('the area of your rectangle is',area,'cm')

    elif choice == '4':
        user_num3= int(input(+Name+' please enter a number: '))
        user_num4= int(input('Now enter a second number: '))
        div= user_num3/user_num4
        print(div)

    elif choice == '5':
        Name = input('Hello Please enter your name?: ')
        user_fav_sub = input('What is your favourite subject?: ')
        print ('OMG '+user_fav_sub+' is my favourite aswell')

    elif choice == '6':
        Name = input ('Hello what is your name?: ')
        if Name =='Zak':
            print ('You\'re cool')
        else:
            print ('Nice to meet you')

    elif choice == '7':
        user_tv = input ('Hi '+Name+' how long do you spend watching TV?: ')
        if user_tv <= '2':
            print ('That shouldn\'t rit your brain too much')
        elif user_tv<='4':
            print ('Aren\'t you getting square eyes')
        else:
            print ('Fresh air beats channel flicking')

    elif choice == '8':
        user_mark = int(input('Hi '+Name+' how many marks did you get on your test?: '))
```

this is where the problem is

```
        if user_mark < '35':
           print ('You got a grade D')
        elif user_mark>='35':
            print ('You got a grade C')
        elif user_mark>='60':
            print ('You got a grade B')
        else:
            print('You got an A')




    else:
        print('Sorry incorect input please try again')
```

Comment: user_mark < '35' (and all other conditions) -> it's string, to check equality, convert these numbers, first.

Comment: And the clue is we cannot compare an integer with a string - `user_mark < '35'`

Comment: Please format your question using the editor, put all as code.  Since indentation is critical in Python, make sure your question shows exactly the code you run.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string with integer. user_mark is an int and you compare it with a string.

Remove quotes from the if else block.

```
    if user_mark < 35:
       print ('You got a grade D')
    elif user_mark>=35:
        print ('You got a grade C')
    elif user_mark>=60:
        print ('You got a grade B')
    else:
        print('You got an A')
```

Comment: `('100'<'35') is True`, so the first method won't work.

Comment: If you compare strings directly, you're doing something similar to C's `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't check the user's input...

The code below should work for you:

```
def isInt(value):
  try:
    int(value)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    print('Sorry, must enter a number...')
    return False

def intInRange(value,num1, num2):
    if isInt(value):
        value = int(value)
        if value in range(num1, num2):
            return True
        print('Enter a number between:',num1,'to',num2)
    return False


def challenges():
    Name = input('Hello Please enter your name:     ')
    print('Hi ' + Name + ', there are 8 challenges to review')
    choice = 'Go'
    while not choice == 'Exit':
        options = '\n*** Options ***' \
               '\n  1. How old are you?' \
               '\n  2. Average' \
               '\n  3. Rectangle area' \
               '\n  4. Divide' \
               '\n  5. Favorite' \
               '\n  6. What is your name?' \
               '\n  7. How much time do you spend on T.V?' \
               '\n  8. Grade check' \
               '\n  To stop, enter Exit'

        print(options)

        choice = input('\nPlease enter your choice between 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8: ')
        while not intInRange(choice, 1, 15):
            print(options)
            choice = input('\nPlease enter your choice between 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8: ')

        choice = int(choice)
        if choice == 1:
            user_age = input('How old are you?: ')
            while not isInt(user_age):
                user_age = input('How old are you?: ')
            print ('You are',user_age,'years old')

        elif choice == 2:
            user_num1 = input('Hi ' + Name + ' please enter your first number: ')
            while not isInt(user_num1):
                user_num1 = input('Hi ' + Name + ' please enter your first number: ')
            user_num2 = int(input('Please enter your second number: '))
            while not isInt(user_num2):
                user_num2 = int(input('Please enter your second number: '))

            total = int(user_num1) + int(user_num2)
            average = total / 2
            print(average)

        elif choice == 3:
            width = input('Please enter your width: ')
            while not isInt(width):
                width = input('Please enter your width: ')

            height = input('Please enter your height: ')
            while not isInt(height):
                height = input('Please enter your height: ')
            area = int(width) * int(height)
            print('The area of your rectangle is', area, 'cm')

        elif choice == 4:
            user_num3 = input(Name + ' please enter a number: ')
            while not isInt(user_num3):
                user_num3 = input(Name + ' please enter a number: ')

            user_num4 = input('Now enter a second number: ')
            while not isInt(user_num4):
                user_num4 = input('Now enter a second number: ')
            div = int(user_num3) / int(user_num4)
            print('The first number divided by the second number =',div)

        elif choice == 5:
            Name = input('Hello Please enter your name?: ')
            user_fav_sub = input('What is your favourite subject?: ')
            print('OMG ' + user_fav_sub + ' is my favourite as well')

        elif choice == 6:
            Name = input('Hello what is your name?: ')
            if Name == 'Zax':
                print('You\'re cool')
            else:
                print('Nice to meet you')

        elif choice == 7:
            user_tv = input('Hi ' + Name + ' how long do you spend watching TV?: ')
            while not isInt(user_tv):
                user_tv = input('Hi ' + Name + ' how long do you spend watching TV?: ')
            user_tv = int(user_tv)
            if user_tv <= 2:
                print('That shouldn\'t rit your brain too much')
            elif user_tv <= 4:
                print('Aren\'t you getting square eyes')
            else:
                print('Fresh air beats channel flicking')

        elif choice == 8:
            user_mark = input('Hi ' + Name + ' how many marks did you get on your test?: ')
            while not intInRange(user_mark,0,101):
                user_mark = input('Hi ' + Name + ' how many marks did you get on your test?: ')

            user_mark = int(user_mark)
            if user_mark < 35:
                print('You got a grade D')
            elif user_mark in range(35,60):
                print('You got a grade C')
            elif user_mark in range(60,80):
                print('You got a grade B')
            else:
                print('You got an A')

        else:
            print('Sorry incorrect input please try again')

challenges()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def challenges():
    Name = input('Hello Please enter your name?: ')
    while True:
        choice = input('Hi '+Name+' there are 30 challenges to reveiw please enter your choice between 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15: ')
        if choice == '1':
            user_age = int(input('How old are you?: '))
            print ('You are',user_age,'years old')

    elif choice == '2':
        user_num1 = int(input('Hi '+Name+' please enter your first number: '))
        user_num2 = int(input('Please enter your second number: '))
        total = user_num1+user_num2
        average = total/2
        print (average)

    elif choice == '3':
        width = int(input('Please enter your width: '))
        height = int(input('Please enter your height: '))
        area = width*height
        print ('the area of your rectangle is',area,'cm')

    elif choice == '4':
        user_num3= int(input(+Name+' please enter a number: '))
        user_num4= int(input('Now enter a second number: '))
        div= user_num3/user_num4
        print(div)

    elif choice == '5':
        Name = input('Hello Please enter your name?: ')
        user_fav_sub = input('What is your favourite subject?: ')
        print ('OMG '+user_fav_sub+' is my favourite aswell')

    elif choice == '6':
        Name = input ('Hello what is your name?: ')
        if Name =='Zak':
            print ('You\'re cool')
        else:
            print ('Nice to meet you')

    elif choice == '7':
        user_tv = input ('Hi '+Name+' how long do you spend watching TV?: ')
        if user_tv <= '2':
            print ('That shouldn\'t rit your brain too much')
        elif user_tv<='4':
            print ('Aren\'t you getting square eyes')
        else:
            print ('Fresh air beats channel flicking')

    elif choice == '8':
        user_mark = input('Hi '+Name+' how many marks did you get on your test?: ')
        if user_mark < '35':
           print ('You got a grade D')
        elif user_mark>='35':
            print ('You got a grade C')
        elif user_mark>='60':
            print ('You got a grade B')
        else:
            print('You got an A')




    else:
        print('Sorry incorect input please try again')
```